# How to manage the way router shares traffic

Tags: networking, router, traffic-management

I just came here from stackoverflow, hope it's the right place to ask this question.

We share internet in our apartment via a Linksys router (2 people are connected with wireless and 2 people with Ethernet cable). The channel is 15 Mbit, which should be enough, but when someone starts to download something on max speed, no one else can even open a web page. Is there a way to tell the router to share traffic among peers? Or it does not distinguish between connected computers and just redirects packets?

Another solution would be using a download manager with speed control but my roommates are lazy :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can install [DD-WRT firmware](http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/dd-wrt/hardware.html) on your router. It has 2 types of QoS: HFSC and HTB

[image: DD-wrt QoS]

It also has:

- service based priority
- mac based piority
- ip based priority
- port based piority

Comment: HFSC is broken in DD-WRT AFAIK (sometimes more, sometimes less, but they admit that in their own wiki and forum), thus everyone is highly recommend to use HTB until they finally fix this once and for all. Just a little tip (using DD-WRT myself at home)

Comment: Yes, I use DD-WRT with HTB. But not from the GUI which proved useless for me. I've made a custom script where I not only distinguish between computers, but also prioritize based on how much data the connection has transferred. This shoves the hogs away quickly leaving the web snappy. But be prepared to spend a lot of time tweaking it. Also make sure you eliminate bufferbloat on your WiFi: `ifconfig ra0 txqueuelen 3` (replace ra0 with your interface)